# Сокращение идентичного jQuery кода

Tags: jquery, минификация

Постепенно изучаю jQuery и учусь писать если не идеально правильный, то хотя бы похожий на него код. Есть несколько почти идентичных форм на сайте и под каждую написан свой jQuery код(меняются поля, их обработка и sendmail.php). По сути это одно и тоже с разным названием и хотел бы узнать как можно сократить.

Пример с проверкой имени и телефона, который используется в каждой форме:

```
var nameval   = $("#name").val();
var namevalid = validateName(nameval);
var phoneval   = $("#phone").val();
var phonevalid = validatePhone(phoneval);

if(namevalid == false) {
    $(".field-name").addClass("error");
}
else if(namevalid == true){
    $(".field-name").removeClass("error");
}

if(phonevalid == false) {
    $(".field-phone").addClass("error");
}
else if(phonevalid == true){
    $(".field-phone").removeClass("error");
}
```

Так же, чтобы проверка работала, в каждой секции с формой есть код:

```
function validateName(name) {
    var reg =  /^[а-яё\s]+$/iu;
    return reg.test(name);
}
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var reg =  /[0-9,\s]/i;
    return reg.test(phone);
}
```

Что, как мне кажется, тоже есть не совсем правильно и это должно быть глобально.

Возможно есть какие-либо документации или статьи на эту тему? Чтобы это не было просто CTRL+C/V.

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать плагины валидации или [маски](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) на jQuery?

Comment: `$(".field-name").attr("error", namevalid);` css: `input[error] { color: red; }` Я бы сделал так.

Comment: Можешь тут глянуть как через css и атрибуты ошибки показывать, недавно делал [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Doofy/yedobo9h)

Comment: Спасибо за наводку @RifmaMan, с маской отпала необходимость в `function validatePhone(phone)`.  
Так же спасибо @Mr.Black за подсказку. С помощью неё удалось сократить и другие части кода.

Answer (score 0):

*не в качестве ответа, а поскольку в коммент кода толком не добавишь.*

1. сравнивать булевые выражения с true/false
2. зачем повторять `if` в ветке `else`
3. почему вместо всего этого просто не использовать `toggleClass`
4. почему бы не обернуть всю повторяющуюся логику в функцию?

---

*условно:*

```
var conf = [
         { field: "name", check: nameValid },
         { field: "phone", check: phoneValid },
      ];

conf.forEach(function(cfg){
       var $f =  $(".field-" + cfg.field);
       var valid = cfg.check( $f.val() );
       $f.toggleClass('has-error', valid);
}) ;
```